# Find maximum int value from list which contain both str and int python

Tags: python, string, list, max, combinations

Looking to find `max` from the combine list as follows:

```
['filename1', 1696, 'filename2', 5809,....]
```

I have tried following:

```
max(['filename1', 1696, 'filename2', 5809,....])
```

that return me `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`. Any suggestion would help. What I want is to find the `max` integer value from the list above mentioned.

Comment: what would you expect if you compare 'filename1' and '1696' ?

Comment: Why are you mixing strings and ints in the same list? Maybe you should have a list of tuples, or a list of dictionaries?

Comment: What is greater - "filename1" or 1696?

Comment: @Psytho wait, I know that one!

Comment: @Barmar I am not mixing it. It what I get from some other API response.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo No. I don't want to compare 'filename1' with '1696' but based upon int value, I have to select de-select previous indexed str value. I am not very good at english but I hope I made that clear to you now.

Comment: @Psytho I have rephrase my question. I am not comparing `str` with `int`. I want to find maximum from `int` values within list. Without affecting the `str` values.

Answer (score 5):

Use `list comprehension` with `isinstance` to extract the `int` and then use `max`.

**Ex:**

```
f = ['filename1', 1696, 'filename2', 5809]
print(max([i for i in f if isinstance(i, int)]))
#or generator
print(max((i for i in f if isinstance(i, int))))    #Better Option
```

**Output:**

```
5809
5809
```

Comment: @khelwood. Thanks. I did not think of that.

Comment: In the generator example the inner `()` are implicit and not needed (as long as the generator is the sole argument).

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks for the answer. It is more like general in terms with different datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

If your real data also has alternating strings and integers, like your example, you can just iterate in steps of size 2, starting with the second element:

```
values = ['filename1', 1696, 'filename2', 5809, ...]
max(values[1::2])
# 5809
```

Note that this slicing creates a new list (so depending on the size of the original list it might be very large).

Answer (score 1):

`max()` expects iterable with comparable values. You should ignore string first from the list and then use `max()` on it.

Use list comprehension to only consider integer values

```
file_data = ['filename1', 1696, 'filename2', 5809,....]
max([elem for elem in file_data if isinstance(elem, int)])
```

If you are expecting float values as well, you can update it as:

```
max([elem for elem in file_data if not isinstance(elem, str)])
```

Answer (score 1):

The same **isinstance** idea can be applied to a filter:

```py
f = ['filename1', 1696, 'filename2', 5809]
max(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), f))
```

Also, if you need to include more than one data type in your comparison,
e.g.: **floats**, you can simple use a tuple to validate the the data to be compared:

```py
max(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, (int, float)), f))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `try...except` clause.

```
lst = ['filename1', 1696, 'filename2', 5809]
numbers = []

for item in lst:
    try:
        numbers.append(int(item))
    except ValueError:
        pass # Ignore items which are not numbers

print(max(numbers))
# 5809
```